# Date change event not getting triggered in angular

Tags: angular, datepicker

I have being working on angular 4 and not able to call a function when date changes, as code below. I am not able to call function  getDateSales() when date changes.

Can someone please help in this.

Thanks in advance.

```
<input class="card-header-action" type="text"
                    placeholder="Select date of sales"
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="saleDate"
                    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
                    bsDaterangepicker
                    (change)="getDateSales()">
```

Comment: subscribe to bsValueChange event to get selected date range in your component for  detail check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need here is add `(bsValueChange)="onValueChange($event)"` event like below

**HTML**

```
<input class="card-header-action" type="text"
                    placeholder="Select date of sales"
                    class="form-control"
                    [(ngModel)]="saleDate"
                    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
                    bsDaterangepicker
                    (bsValueChange)="getDateSales($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-value-change-event',
  templateUrl: './value-change-event.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerValueChangeEventComponent {
  data: Date;

  onValueChange(value: Date): void {
    this.data = value;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Yes this worked!!!.. but model saleDate doesn't get this value... we have to explicitly assign the value as you have shown...

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to datepicker's value [change](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#value-change-event) event

```
<input class="card-header-action" type="text"
                        placeholder="Select date of sales"
                        class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="saleDate"
                        [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"
                        bsDaterangepicker
                        (bsValueChange)="getDateSales()">
```

Comment: yes this works but needed to add getDateSales($event)